# Make QGraphicsItem move

Tags: c++, qt5

How can I enforce QGraphicsItem move as if the user held down the left mouse button and started dragging the item?

Namely, the user will press the "add" button, after which the item should appear on the scene immediately in a moving state.

Guess I need to grab the mouse, but it looks dangerous.

Comment: Do not be scared, try and find out.

Comment: Where would `QGraphicsItem` appear exactly? And where would it move, and where would it stop moving?

Comment: And does the user have to press down left mouse button?

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayene It is desirable that the item appears where the cursor is now. It should move with the mouse. I mean, it should behave as if the user has started dragging it, but with no buttons pressed. And should stop when the user clicks the mouse.

Comment: But you mentioned that the user has to click a button in order for the item to appear. So the item cannot have the same position as the cursor, because it would be placed on top of the button, and this is in case you have your button inside you graphicsView, did I get it right? If yes, do you see the problem I'm talking about?

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayene In the case of a regular widget, I could grab the mouse and move the item all over the screen, even when it's not over the QGraphicsView. However, in the case of `QGraphicsItem`, the `grabMouse` method does not seem to work properly, the mouse is not captured globally, the item only captures events for the scene. This is probably because `QGraphicsItem` is not a widget, and does not derive from `QObject` at all. There are not even signals and slots. In addition, the item will not be drawn if you try to move it outside the QGraphicsView. Thank you, I understand the problem.

Comment: `grabMouse` will only disable mouse input for everything else but your item, which is not what you need. Have you tried using [hoverEnterEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverEnterEvent), [hoverLeaveEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverLeaveEvent), [hoverMoveEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverMoveEvent), [mousePressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent)?